# stress-ng failing with temp-path '.' must be readable

Tags: command-line, permissions

Ultimately, I want to execute stress-ng from a php script.

In testing, I've realized it runs fine from the CLI under my account (in folders where I have permission). It also runs fine as root. But as sudo, it DOESN'T run. And I'm going to presume that's why the script won't execute either. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The command:

```
sudo stress-ng --temp-path /tmp/stress-tmp/ -c 10 -t 10
```

The error:

```
aborting: temp-path '.' must be readable and writeable
```

The underlying system is Ubuntu.

`/tmp/stress-tmp` is chmod-ed to 777 (for now, until I figure out what the deal is).

I've tried chown-ing `/tmp/stress-tmp` to multiple users (me, root, www-data, etc) with no change.

It also seems weird that I'm specifying the temp-folder, but I'm being told the current directory (no matter where I execute from) isn't readable or (ahem) writeable (sic).

Thanks (as always) in advance.

Comment: If your `/tmp/stress-tmp` is 777 (which is normal for things under `/tmp`) and you are getting this error, then you're probably not actually in `/tmp/stress-tmp`. You haven't told us how you execute this, are you running it through a php script which is executed by a webserver or have you simply run the `stress-ng` command manually from a terminal? If the former, try running `pwd` in the same way to see what directory it reports.

Comment: I'm running the comment (sudo stress-ng --temp-path /tmp/stress-tmp/ -c 10 -t 10) from the CLI and getting that error. That's why it's confusing me so much.

And I'm executing it from /tmp/stress-tmp (or ~/ or just about anywhere). Still getting the error. That's why this is bugging me so much.

And just to clarify: once I get this working from the CLI, I believe I'll understand why executing from a php script (using an exec() or backtic instruction) is failing. But I'm trying to work my way up to that.

Comment: run sudo strace -f stress-ng --temp-path /tmp/stress-tmp/ -c 10 -t 10 and then look at the output, you will see the open failure on /tmp/stess-tmp and that will provide more information on why it is failing